# Web security - use of cookie in https

Tags: tls, cookies

I am taking a web security class and was told by the instructor that most of the websites today use https for authentication and then use a cookie (authentication token) in plain text to keep track of the user.

I wanted to confirm this. For example, when I use Amazon.com, if I logged in before, Amazon shows something relevant to my history. For this they must be using a cookie. But when I click on Account, a https page is opened. If I am looking at my account details, why would Amazon choose to send a cookie (acting as an authentication token) in plain text ? If I can listen over the wire, can't I just steal the cookie and hijack someone's session ?

My hypothesis is that websites like Amazon have multiple cookies, some are for pages that don't need https (like the home page), but still want to keep track of user history; others are for tracking if user authenticated previously (so user doesn't need to type password again), and this type of cookie must always be sent over https.

Can anyone confirm my hypothesis ? (I believe my instructor might not be entirely correct)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be achieved in a relatively secure manner with two cookies.

One has the [Secure Flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) set, and will contain your HTTPS session details and is used through out the checkout process when making a purchase. The [Secure Flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) ensures that the browser only sends the cookie over connections protected by SSL/TLS (i.e. use the HTTPS protocol).

The other does not have this flag set, and will store the HTTP session details. The session details stored on the server side could be items viewed, or if you have previously logged in it could tie your session up to an account. This is what would be used when the site says **Welcome John** when you return without logging in.

For this to work, there should be no way of determining the secure session cookie value from the insecure one.

The insecure cookie could be used up to the point of entering the checkout or the account details pages, where a login over HTTPS is then required where the secure session cookie is then set. This would stop a [MITM attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) from obtaining the cookie, as if an attacker stole the insecure cookie the worst they could do is alter the browsing history of the user, or add/remove things from the basket. If it was implemented in this way it would be assumed the user would check that the basket items copied to their secure session are the ones they actually wanted to order before completing checkout (or that they read their confirmation email and cancel items later).

It is not clear from your question whether your instructor is referring to the sending of plain text cookies carefully using good practise like the above, or as a bad example of how not to do it. If the latter, many websites do in fact only protect certain pages such as login and card details pages with HTTPS, but then go on to use the same authentication or session cookie over HTTP pages too, not realising that this cookie value is sent in the clear and can be read by a suitably placed attacker.

Comment: So my instructor is wrong then ?

Comment: @Jake: I've just updated my answer addressing your point.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if the site is fully HTTPS, then the entire site is encrypted (headers, cookies and all). Learn more about SSL [here](http://wpengine.com/support/how-does-all-this-work-https-ssl-certificates-ca-public-and-private-keys-csrs/).

With Amazon, they basically use a mix of secure private data (your logged in session) and insecure *'private'* data (your IP address).

There are two basic ways a site can 'track' you like you described so that when you first go to Amazon.com, you visit the non-SSL homepage and it may 'magically' show you a bunch of suggested items.

1. Stores a local (on your machine) cookie and sends that cookie to Amazon saying, 'hey, this is me'. This cookie could be encrypted or not and depending on what info is actually stored in the cookie, it may or may not be a security risk.
2. A site could also do this without storing anything with you locally. They do this by simply tying your IP address (which is sent as a part of any HTTP request -in plain text) to a matching IP that it has on file for you and volia.

While your example of Amazon does not send *secure* plain-text cookies and therefore there isnt much risk of what you described as a [MiTM attack](http://www.veracode.com/security/man-middle-attack), these types of attacks can happen -especially if the '[secure flag](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/securing-cookies-httponly-secure-flags/)' is not set with the cookie.

NOTE: You can check all this stuff out (view the http/https requests, see cookies, etc) for yourself by using a packet sniffer like wireshark or even just a browser debugger like firebug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But could you also comment about the Amazon example I gave ? I'm sure Amazon is not entirely https, but they use cookie throughout the site.

Comment: As far as I know, Amazon is fully secure (once you are logged in and on an SSL secured page). Some sites do make mistakes here and there and reference an insecure img src or something but it is definitely considered bad practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> Cookies can be used for both session management and Tracking users behaviour.

Many cookies can be placed by a single website each present to provide different functionality. Depends on the implementation how cookies are used.
 Some can be placed using secure and HTTPonly tags.

> Social sites and other websites show advertisements tracking user behaviour also have the connection with the e-commerce site.

So according to me, some cookies are left unsecured for advertisements or many be shared among different domains like just an example, Facebook shows advertisements of what I saw on amazon last time. Or just my google search of some product is being shown to me on some other sites.While some are secure for user auth, payments, user personal and bank info.. etc